# jQuery token input rails getting error Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tokenInput'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-tokeninput

So I am using [rails cast #258](http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields) as reference and am getting stuck when I try an load the page the javascript that adds the token input to the text field dosen't seem to be attaching properly. In the chrome console I am getting this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tokenInput'

If anyone has any idea as to what I am missing that would be most appreciated.

Comment: Are you including the Token Input jQuery plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the Token Input jQuery plugin - at http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/

Answer (score 0):

check the view source and see if tokeninput is included in that page.

And if it is included then it is included after jquery and also make sure jquery is not conflicted by using alert in document ready.

I think that should solve your problems.